# how to retrieve blob Object from sqlite in Blackberry java

Tags: java, sqlite, blackberry-jde

I am, retrieving blob objects which is in db, While retrieving in the second time, I am getting error as **java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Row index 1 out of valid range**

Code which i am using as below

```
d = DatabaseFactory.open(myURI);
        st = d.createStatement(queryStatement); 
        st.prepare();
        net.rim.device.api.database.Cursor c = st.getCursor();
        Vector list = new Vector();
        Row r;
        int i = 0;          
        System.out.println("C Value is >>>>>"+c.getPosition());     
        while (c.next()) {
                System.out.println("Row Count >>>>> "+i);
                Row row = c.getRow();
                is= row.getBlobStream(i);//this is place I am getting error
                byteArray.reset();
                        is.reset();
        }
```

Is this wrong way of invocation?

Comment: Is this really the actual code? Doesn't `i` get incremented somewhere?

Comment: this is first column index